# InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I'm trying to update item security while adding new item but getting following error. How to find the problem from this trace ?

> Stack Trace:   [InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due
>   to the current state of the object.]
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.InitSecurity() +26790031
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.get_SecurableObjectImpl() +16
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurableObject.get_RoleAssignments() +10
>   updatelistpermission(SPWeb web, SharedSurveyHeader objEntity,
>   SPListItem lstItem, String strStatus) +816
>   routine.<>c_*DisplayClass3.b*_0() +688
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.<>c_*DisplayClass4.b*_2()
>   +729    Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated
>   secureCode) +27947702
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback
>   secureCode, Object param) +27648393
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated
>   secureCode) +93

Here is my code,

```
   try
            {
                {
                    SPUserToken token = SPContext.Current.Web.Site.SystemAccount.UserToken;

                    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                    {
                        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Site.ID, token))
                        {
                            site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(SPContext.Current.Web.ID))
                            {
                                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                                web.BreakRoleInheritance(true);
                                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                                SPList lstProject = web.Lists["SharedHeader"];
                                SPListItem lstItem = lstProject.Items.Add();
                                loadToListItem(sharedHeader, ref lstItem, true);
                                updatelistpermission(web, sharedHeader, lstItem, strStatus);
                                lstItem.Update();
                                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                                intResult = lstItem.ID;
                                lstItem = null;
                                lstProject = null;
                            }
                        }
                    });


                }

             }



  private static void updatelistpermission(SPWeb web, SharedSurveyHeader objEntity, SPListItem lstItem,string strStatus)
    {
         try
        {

                        SPRoleDefinition roleUserDefintion = null;
                        SPRoleDefinition roleSupervisorDefintion = null;
                        SPRoleDefinition roleOpManagerDefintion = null;

                        if (strStatus == "Active")
                        {
                            roleUserDefintion = web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.Contributor);
                            roleSupervisorDefintion = web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.Reader);
                            roleOpManagerDefintion = web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.Reader);
                        }
                        else if (strStatus == "Submitted")
                        {
                            roleUserDefintion = web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.Reader);
                            roleSupervisorDefintion = web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.Contributor);
                            roleOpManagerDefintion = web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.Contributor);
                        }
                        else if (strStatus == "Completed")
                        {
                            roleUserDefintion = web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.Reader);
                            roleSupervisorDefintion = web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.Reader);
                            roleOpManagerDefintion = web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.Reader);
                        }

                        SPUser uParticipant = Utility.convertStringToSPUser(Utility.getSPStringLookupFromListGLT(objEntity.Participant));
                        SPRoleAssignment roleUserAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(uParticipant);

                        SPUser uSupervisor = Utility.convertStringToSPUser(Utility.getSPStringLookupFromListGLT(objEntity.Supervisor));
                        SPRoleAssignment roleSupervisorAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(uSupervisor);

                        SPUser uOpManager = Utility.convertStringToSPUser(Utility.getSPStringLookupFromListGLT(objEntity.OpsManager));
                        SPRoleAssignment roleuOpManagerAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(uOpManager);

                        roleUserAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(roleUserDefintion);
                        lstItem.RoleAssignments.Add(roleUserAssignment);

                        roleSupervisorAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(roleSupervisorDefintion);
                        lstItem.RoleAssignments.Add(roleSupervisorAssignment);

                        roleuOpManagerAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(roleOpManagerDefintion);
                        lstItem.RoleAssignments.Add(roleuOpManagerAssignment);

        }
        catch (SPException spex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the segment of code with below code:

```
using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(SPContext.Current.Web.ID))
{
    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

    SPList lstProject = web.Lists["SharedHeader"];
    //lstProject.BreakRoleInheritance(true);
    //lstProject.Update();

    lstProject = web.Lists["SharedHeader"];
    SPListItem lstItem = lstProject.Items.Add();
    loadToListItem(sharedHeader, ref lstItem, true);
    lstItem.Update();

    lstItem = lstProject.GetItemById(lstItem.ID);
    lstItem.BreakRoleInheritance(false);
    lstItem.Update();

    lstItem = lstProject.GetItemById(lstItem.ID);
    updatelistpermission(web, sharedHeader, lstItem, strStatus);
    lstItem.Update();

    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
    intResult = lstItem.ID;
    lstItem = null;
    lstProject = null;
}
```

When you are adding the Item until `lstItem.Update()` is not called, the Item is not made in the list... and thus you cannot set permissions on the Item which doesn't exist!

So first you need to call `lstItem.Update` to create the Item in the list and then get the new Item again by `list.GetItemById()` and then set the permissions on the Item!

UPDATE:
I have updated the code above!
Please follow [this article](http://www.thespgeek.com/2011/08/assigning-sharepoint-list-item-level.html)

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @Arsalan Adam Khatri. Now I'm getting following error 

**"This operation is not allowed on an object that inherits permissions."**

Even I have added 

**web.BreakRoleInheritance(true);**

Comment: Rishi, I have updated the code above!

Comment: I've updated the code as you mentioned but still the same error **Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: This operation is not allowed on an object that inherits permissions.**

Comment: Can you check stop inheriting permissions on List and Web manually - and try running the code?

Comment: Permission of the list is already broken , It seems first part of the code where we are breaking the permission of the list and saving works.

Comment: I have updated the code... I hope now it will work!

Comment: Arsalan, Permission of the web is broken too. Tried your updated code but still same error :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6291/discussion-between-arsalan-adam-khatri-and-rishi)

Comment: Arsalan, Your updated code works now. Don't I need to break inheritance for the list. Will this code work if list inheritance is not broken ? Thanks a lot for your effort.